# How to remove negative values from a list using lambda functions by python

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have implemented a lambda function to sort a list. now i want to remove all the negative objects from the list by using lambda functions .

```
dto_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.count, reverse=True)
```

any one know a way to write the lambda expression to do it? I could not find a proper tutorial

Comment: Do you have to use a `lambda`? Usually they are unnecessary and make code less readable.

Comment: FYI the pythonic way to do the above is `sorted(dto_list, key=operator.attrgetter("count"), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not very pythonic but here is how to do it with a lambda

```
>>> L = list(range(-10,10))
>>> L
[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> filter(lambda x: x >= 0, L)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Most people would use a list comprehension

```
>>> [x for x in L if x >= 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: any one know python standards for list operations ? whether to use lambda functions? what are the good practices ?

Comment: @Kalanamith: The "standard" is to use whatever is **shortest and easiest to understand**. Sometimes that will be a list comprehension; sometimes it will be `itertools`; sometimes that will be a `lambda` function used with `map()`, `filter()`, or `reduce()`. *You* get to make the call as to which one is better for your application.